# JWT authentication in django rest framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm new to django_rest_framework and trying to implement JWT authentication . But there is a problem however I send the token that created by username and password that has been sent but this error fires out.

```
{"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

**Generating Token:**

```
TOKEN_ENDPOINT = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/auth/token/'

user_data = {
    'username': 'admin',
    'password': 1234
}
json_user_data = json.dumps(user_data)
user_headers = {
    'content-type': 'application/json'
}

token_response = requests.request('post', TOKEN_ENDPOINT, data=json_user_data, headers=user_headers)
token = token_response.json()['token']
```

**Sending new post request with generated token:**

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Authorization": "JWT" + token,
}
data = json.dumps({"content": "Hellllllllloooo"})
new_content_req = requests.post(ENDPOINT, data=data,
                            headers=headers)

print(new_content_req.text) // {"detail":"Authentication credentials were not provided."}
```

**REST_FRAMEWORK Default authentication and permissions:**

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication',
        'rest_framework_jwt.authentication.JSONWebTokenAuthentication',
    ), 
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': (
        'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    )
}


JWT_AUTH = {
    'JWT_ENCODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_encode_handler',

    'JWT_DECODE_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_decode_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_payload_handler',

    'JWT_PAYLOAD_GET_USER_ID_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_get_user_id_from_payload_handler',

    'JWT_RESPONSE_PAYLOAD_HANDLER':
    'rest_framework_jwt.utils.jwt_response_payload_handler',

    'JWT_ALLOW_REFRESH': True,
    'JWT_REFRESH_EXPIRATION_DELTA': datetime.timedelta(days=7),

    'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
    'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
}
```

**Prefix:**

```
'JWT_AUTH_HEADER_PREFIX': 'JWT',
'JWT_AUTH_COOKIE': None,
```

**View:**

```
class StatusAPIView(mixins.CreateModelMixin, generics.ListAPIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly]
    # authentication_classes = [SessionAuthentication]
    queryset = Status.objects.all()
    serializer_class = StatusSerializer

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.create(request, *args, **kwargs)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a space after `JWT`

```
headers = {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    "Authorization": "JWT " + token,
}
data = json.dumps({"content": "Hellllllllloooo"})
new_content_req = requests.post(ENDPOINT, data=data,
                            headers=headers)

print(new_content_req.text)
```